# How to get the field_image path with Twig in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig

To make an animated slider, I overwrite a fields view template file in my own template named: views-view-fields--slider.html.twig

Inside that file I have access to a fields array to print out all the fields that are in my content-type *slide*.

The problem is that I need to get the path of the image file instead of the image itself, because I need the path for CSS background-image styling.

The following doesn't work:

```
<div class="jumbotron " ref="" style="background-image:url(?????);">
   {{ file_url(fields.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}
</div>
```

I tried everything I good find on Google:

```
fields.field_image.entity.uri
fields.field_image.entity.uri.value
fields.field_image.entity.url
fields.field_image.entity.url.value
```

etc.

Has anyone an idea how it is done in Drupal 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this module: image_url_formatter, so in View interface, I can use this to formatter my image filed as path.

It works perfect, but if I turned the twig debug on, it wouldn't work, because it will output debug annotation. I don't know how to solved it yet.

I use fields.field_image.content to show the path, I don't konw whether it's rignt.

---

**Solution without extra module:**

In your Views:

1.Add your image filed to the Advanced/Relationship

2.Then in the filed section, change to File Group, you can see URI field，add it, and make sure you check "Display the file download URI"

3.Add your new field in the twig template: {{ field.uri.content }}

Done!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this module. I'm also not sure why an extra module is needed, there should be a entity.fileuri or something like that.

Comment: content.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value works in 'node' template, in 'views' template, there is no 'entity' property for field

Comment: Thank you the relationship solution works, only twig debug output around the path breaks my inline background-image css line

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in views-view-unformatted you should already have access individualy to each field of your content type *Slide* with `{{ row.content }}` and because of that you have to do:

`{{ file_url(row.content.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The above jumbotron div is inside views-view-fields--slider.html.twig and I also have a surrounding file views-view-unformatted--slider.html.twig which is printing row.content. row.content.field_image.entity.fileuri is still empty :(

Comment: Ok, you could try `{{ file_url(fields.field_image['#items'].entity.fileuri) }}` then

Comment: I'm sorry, the output is still empty. <div class="jumbotron " ref="" style="background-image:url('');">/</div>

Answer (score 2):

Try `{{ file_url(row._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}`.
It works for me.

```
<div style="background-image:url({{ file_url(row._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value) }});"></div>
```